# Force NIS to use TCP

Tags: linux, networking, nis

Is it possible to force NIS to connect using TCP instead of UDP?  I've scoured the documentation for both `ypserv` (to force listening on TCP only) and `ypbind` (to connect over TCP only) but found nothing (only an option to specify the listening *port*).  I'm afraid somebody is going to answer "yes, if you compile from source..."

And `ypserv` listens on both protocols, so why doesn't `ypbind` try TCP when UDP fails?

**Update**

I tried Phil's solution, but it turns out that ypbind first contacts portmap on UDP port 111.  If it doesn't get a UDP response it just gives up.

Answer (score 1):

I could only come up with one solution, and a quick google [shows the same](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/nis-server-on-specifc-tcp-udp-ports-657801/).  Run ypserv on a specific port, then configure iptables on the server to block incoming udp connections, for example if you are running ybserv on say port 1337:

```
# iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 1337 -j REJECT
```

although I am unclear what mechanism ybbind uses to determine whether to use UDP or TCP.  Using a firewall rule like that might just result in ypbind attempting a UDP connection, getting blocked, and giving up.